# Testing React store with mock functions

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm new to react and development in general. I want to unit test react `store.dispatch` action and whether it returns the corresponding `type` and `payload`. My current code structure is having an underneath function to be executed before it returns the expected `type` and `payload`.

Example:

```js
export function requestForSomething(number){
  store.dispatch(getData(number));
}
```

```js
export const getData = number => {
  const productDetails = someFunction(number);
  return { 
    type: GET_DATA,
    productDetails,
  };
}
```

The question is, how can I unit test the above `store.dispatch` with Jest? Is it required to mock or can I mock `someFunction(number)` and how to do that.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a unit test solution, you can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName, accessType?)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) to do this.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';

function reducer(state = {}) {
  return state;
}

export const store = createStore(reducer);

export const GET_DATA = 'GET_DATA';

export function requestForSomething(number) {
  store.dispatch(getData(number));
}

export const getData = number => {
  const productDetails = someFunction(number);
  return {
    type: GET_DATA,
    productDetails
  };
};

export const someFunction = number => {
  return number;
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import * as mod from './';

describe('test suites', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('#requestForSomething', () => {
    const action = { type: 'GET_DATA', productDetails: {} };
    const spy = jest.spyOn(mod, 'getData').mockReturnValueOnce(action);
    const dispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(mod.store, 'dispatch');
    mod.requestForSomething(1);
    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(1);
    expect(dispatchSpy).toBeCalledWith(action);
  });

  it('#getData', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(mod, 'someFunction').mockReturnValueOnce({});
    const actualValue = mod.getData(1);
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({ type: 'GET_DATA', productDetails: {} });
    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(1);
  });

  it('#someFunction', () => {
    const actualValue = mod.someFunction(1);
    expect(actualValue).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58757332/index.spec.ts (7.351s)
  test suites
    ✓ #requestForSomething (5ms)
    ✓ #getData (1ms)
    ✓ #someFunction

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.659s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58757332

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helped. This is exactly what I was after.